# Print struct inputs in alphabetic order C++

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

I want to print strings from a struct in alphabetic order, and I have got help from the thread [How to alphabetically sort strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553097/how-to-alphabetically-sort-strings), for the sorting. My problem is that when i run the compiler i get a sorted output but it includes a name from another struct. My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int antalShops = 2;
const int antalWorkers = 5;

struct employ { 
    string workerName; int workerAge; 
};

struct theMall{
    string shopName; string shopType; int shopSize; 
    employ workerName; employ workerAge; 
};

// Declaration of the structs
theMall Shops[antalShops] = {
    {"GameStop","toy", 250,}, 
    {"Frandsen", "cloth", 300,},
};

employ Workers[antalWorkers] = {
    {"Andrea valente", 41}, 
    {"Giovanni Pirolli", 25}, 
    {"Marco Cipolli", 33},
    {"Jensine Jensen", 19}, 
    {"Andrea Jensen", 99},
};

// Functions for sorting and printing names
void print(const string& item) {
    cout << item << endl;
}

void PrintWorkers(employ Workers[]) {
    set<string> sortedWorkers;
    for(int i = 0; i <= antalWorkers; ++i) {
        sortedWorkers.insert(Workers[i].workerName);
    }
    for_each(sortedWorkers.begin(), sortedWorkers.end(), &print);
}

void PrintShops(theMall Shops[]) {
    set<string> sortedShops;
    for (int i = 0; i <= antalShops; ++i) {
        sortedShops.insert(Shops[i].shopName);
    }
    for_each(sortedShops.begin(), sortedShops.end(), &print);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    PrintShops(Shops);
}
```

So I have the structs with workers and shops, but when I i try printing the shop names with the `PrintShops(Shops)` function i get the output:

```
Andrea Valente
Frandsen
GameStop
```

I have been looking through the code, but i can't find where the mistake is, anyone can see the error?

Comment: Using lowercase identifiers for types and uppercase for variables is extremely confusing.

Comment: Why not use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to sort the arrays in place? Or keep them in a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and copy that vector to one you sort if you don't want to modify the original container.

Comment: You never initialize the two `employ` members of any of your `theMall` structs.

Comment: this is not real code (where did you initialize shops with employees?), please insert real code

Comment: I am pretty new to coding so there is lots of stuff i don't know about yet, the most of the stuff i used in the code is something i learned from programming course.

Comment: This is of course a matter of personal preference, but I would recommend using initial *lower* case letters for variable and function names and initial *upper* case letters for object types. This is what most programmers follow.

Comment: Okay, i will remember that thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go outside the bounds of the arrays in your loops

```
for (int i = 0; i <= antalShops; ++i) {
//   Problem here ^^
```

The above loop will loop over indexes `0`, `1` *and* `2`, which is one to many for a two-entry array. This will lead to *undefined behavior*.

You have the same problem with the other sorting loop.

Comment: This worked, i thought i already tried this, but obvouisly i didn't do it right, but thanks a lot.