# Not sure on how to sort names alphabetically

Tags: c++

Write a program that asks the user to enter three names, and then displays the names

sorted in alphabetical order. Assume that none of the names are the same. For example,

if the user entered Charlie, Leslie, and Andy the program would display:

Andy

Charlie

Leslie

```
//System Libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>//Input/Output Library
using namespace std;

//User Libraries

//Global Constants, no Global Variables are allowed
//Math/Physics/Conversions/Higher Dimensions - i.e. PI, e, etc...

//Function Prototypes

//Execution Begins Here!
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    string name1,
           name2,
           name3;

    cout<<"Sorting Names\n";
    cout<<"Input 3 names\n";
    cin>>name1;
    cin>>name2;
    cin>>name3;

    cout<<name1<<endl;
    cout<<name2<<endl;
    cout<<name3;


    return 0;
}
```

Expected:

Sorting·Names↵
Input·3·names↵
Andy↵
Charly↵
Leslie

Actual:

Sorting·Names↵
Input·3·names↵
Charly↵
Leslie↵
Andy

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: ive reworked my code and posted it below

Comment: It looks like the sorting algorithm is completely missing in that code. So, have you tried to implement it?

Comment: Suggestion: Add a comment to your code stating that as a simplification, you are sorting by character code (lexicographically), not alphabetically, which would be a case-sensitive, locale-specific sort. For the characters in the [ISO Basic Latin Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet), the results would be the same, with all uppercase before all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> sortedItems;



    {
        std::string name1, name2, name3;
        std::cout <<"Sorting Names\n";
        std::cout <<"Input 3 names\n";
        std::cin >> name1;
        std::cin >> name2;
        std::cin >> name3;

        sortedItems.insert(name1);
        sortedItems.insert(name2);
        sortedItems.insert(name3);
    }

    std::sort(sortedItems.begin(), sortedItems.end());

    for(unsigned i=0; i<sortedItems.size();i++) 
    {
        std::cout << sortedItems[i];
        if(i < sortedItems.size() - 1) std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> sortedItems;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        std::string name;
        std::cout << i << ". ";
        std::cin >> name;

        sortedItems.insert(name);
    }

    std::for_each(sortedItems.begin(), sortedItems.end(), &print);
    return 0;
}
```

I found this you can try it is using a for loop to sort and spit the names.
Credit goes to AngelCastillo for he posted this you can see further @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/18582892/10322492

Comment: forsure @ blaze